How did Azazel find out that Dean is one of the baby mediums
In Supernatural, season 4, episode 3, when Cas sends Dean to 1973, Azazel (the demon in Samuel Campbell's body), talking to Dean, said

"if you're Mary's son, then you're one of my baby mediums"

(approximate essence of the conversation)
Question: How did Azazel know that Dean was one of the baby mediums, if this conversation between them took place before Mary Campbell made a deal with him in order to bring John Winchester back to life

I have an answer, but I deleted it because the "spoiler" protection did not seem to take. Let's just say the answer is revealed in subsequent seasons. I did not want to give it away or take away someone else's chance to answer.
